# Expression with Dictionary

Tags: c#, expression

I need to create an expression that extract a specific item from a dictionary.
The topic is to put the name of the item to extract inside the Expression.

I'll try to explain it better with an example.

I have this dictionary:

```
     Dictionary<string, object> myDictionary = new Dictionary<string, object>
     {
         { "Name", "My first name" },
         { "Age", 42 }
     };
```

I wrote this code to compose an Expression that works with IDictionary:

```
    private Expression<Func<IDictionary<string, object>, string, object>> GetDictionaryExpression()
    {
        var dictionary = Expression.Parameter(typeof(IDictionary<string, object>), "dict");

        var keyParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(string));
        var indexer = typeof(IDictionary<string, object>).GetProperty("Item");

        var indexerExpr = Expression.Property(dictionary, indexer, keyParam);
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<IDictionary<string, object>, string, object>>(indexerExpr, dictionary, keyParam);    
    }
```

Finally, I can write this code:

```
        var x = GetDictionaryExpression();
        var y = x.Compile().Invoke(myDictionary, "Name"); // My first name
```

This code works.

What I need is to create an expression that doesn't need the field "Name" at runtime, but put it inside the Expression.
In other words, something that will let me have something like this:

```
        var x = GetNameFromDictionary(); // <== How to write this method that extract only the 'Name' value from the dictionary?
        var y = x.Compile().Invoke(visionRecord); // My first name
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Querying a Dictionary with a Lambda Expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1013440/querying-a-dictionary-with-a-lambda-expression)

Comment: What is `visionRecord`?

Comment: Sorry. It is a copy/paste mistake. It is myDictionary

Comment: I saw the link you gave me, but it didn't help. In that example, people knows the name of the properties at compile time, so they can write a lambda in the common way (code). In my situation, I have to compose the expression at runtime, so can't use that way (I don't know property names when I write the code)